# how do I create a .geojson from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, geojson, converters

I am having trouble with this same code someone else did, but a different issue. Can someone explain to me how the geometry part works? All I want is points and have a list of dictionaries. Do I need any other info to input? It appears it doesn't like the float for lat and lon.

def convert_to_geojson(my_list):
"""
This function converts a list of dictionaries into GeoJSON format
It requires AT LEAST a "lon" and "lat" key in the dictionaries
But may contain any other additional metadata
For example, my_list = [{"lat": 30.321, "lon": 20}]
:param my_list: A list of dictionaries
:return: a GeoJSON string
"""

```
feature_list = []
for d in my_list:
    
    the_geom = {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [d["lon"], d["lat"]]}
    feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": the_geom, "properties": d}
    feature_list.append(feature)

feature_collection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": feature_list}

return json.dumps(feature_collection)
```

the_list = [{"lat": -32.038607, "lon": 115.893494, "location": "Riverton"},
{"lat": -32.064277, "lon": 115.79581, "acc_ID": 8063399, "severity": "Major", "type": "Intersection", "year": 2012, "furtherest": "No"},
{"lat": -31.791455, "lon": 116.050658, "acc_ID": 8063291, "severity": "Hospital", "type": "Midblock", "year": 2012, "furtherest": "Yes"}]

convert_to_geojson(the_list)

import json, GeojsonConverter_3

```
# Now call the function, give it the list and assign what it returns to a variable
the_string = GeojsonConverter_3.convert_to_geojson(the_list)
# Print the GeoJSON to screen so you can see it
print(the_string)

file_pointer = open("GeoJSON_File.geojson", "w")

file_pointer.write(the_string)
```

RESULT

```
 37 
 38     except Exception as e:
```

---> 39         raise e
40
41     else:

24     try:
25         for d in my_list:
---> 26             if(d["lon"].replace(" ", "") is not "") and (d["lat"].replace(" ", "") is not ""):
27                 float(d["lon"])
28                 float(d["lat"])

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Your lat is a float, which is a number, a number with a decimal place after it, and the replace method can't work with floats or strs.

Comment: Then how can I get an accurate position?